# May I ask about study groups or study partners on MSE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This is a good website, but I would prefer to do mathematics "old-school" style and actually sit and study with someone with similar level and interests; and discuss theorems, problems and other fun stuff.

Is there any place on MSE I can ask about people in my city who wish to create/join a study group?

Comment: This would seem like a good place to go to meet math study buddies, but I'm afraid that kind of question is unwelcomed by a good portion of the MSE "community". Going into a MSE chat room might be a good option.

Comment: @BillCook Thanks, didn't even know there was a chat! :) Will check it out.

Comment: *"The funk soul brother, check it out now"*. Sorry, I couldn't resist...

Comment: You may also have a look at [How do I find partners for study?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99198/how-do-i-find-partners-for-study) posted on mine (and on the linked questions.) Although that question is about online collaboration, so it seems to be different from what you want.

Comment: Which tags should I use to ask for study buddies?